# How secure is LUKS encryption?

Tags: encryption, luks

I have encrypted a hardsik with a 12 charachter random alphanumeric passwrod using `LUKS` encryption on Ubuntu 18.04 on a 2.5" SATA disk partitioned with `ext4`.

I'm wondering how secure is such scheme?
In other words, provided that the cracker has the best software and talent, how long does it take to crack such encryption?

Comment: I'd start with the FAQ.  https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5-security-aspects  which uses money as the parameter.  Talent only involves schemes where the software implementation has some flaw.

Comment: How can I aply this `1/2 * 2^(bits of entropy in passphrase)` formula to my case? Not sure what are my bits of entropy.

Comment: LUKS is the container and the encryption used is AES-256. Check this question as a near duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97196/how-secure-is-an-encrypted-luks-filesystem

Comment: @randon If you include upper, lower, and numbers, that's 62 characters.  Which is about 6 bits per character, or 72 bits for 12.  So you're talking trillions of dollars if you're using the key stretching algorithm.

Comment: I see, so please give a complete answer and I'll accept it.